# devstack failing on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install openstack using devstack on Ubuntu 14.04. I am facing the error shown below:

```
2014-11-20 12:05:03.300 | + mysql -uroot -popenstack -h172.16.69.217 -e 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS nova;'
2014-11-20 12:05:03.303 | + mysql -uroot -popenstack -h172.16.69.217 -e 'CREATE DATABASE nova CHARACTER SET latin1;'
2014-11-20 12:05:03.307 | + /usr/local/bin/nova-manage db sync
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |   File "/usr/local/bin/nova-manage", line 6, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |     from nova.cmd.manage import main
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 68, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |     from nova.api.ec2 import ec2utils
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/api/ec2/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |     from nova.api.ec2 import apirequest
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/api/ec2/apirequest.py", line 29, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |     from nova.api.ec2 import ec2utils
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/api/ec2/ec2utils.py", line 28, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.539 |     from nova.objects import base as obj_base
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 |   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/objects/base.py", line 35, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 |     from nova import utils
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 |   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/utils.py", line 39, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 |     from oslo.concurrency import lockutils
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/concurrency/lockutils.py", line 30, in <module>
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 |     from oslo.config import cfgfilter
2014-11-20 12:05:03.540 | ImportError: cannot import name cfgfilter
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to test drive an OpenStack deployment the easiest way to get started is here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

This enables you to deploy a full OpenStack cloud powered by Juju, MAAS, and Landscape (which gives you 10 free virtual and 10 free bare metal seats)